# Ошибка при запуске приложения asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]

Только начал изучать `asp.net` и столкнулся c данной проблемой. При запуске веб приложения `VisualStudio` выдает ошибку. Раньше удавалось запустить приложение с n-ной попытки. Ошибка вылетает на разных проектах, в том числе и не на моих. Текст с изображения:

> Не удаётся запустить программу "http://localhost:22952/001_PageEvents/005_PageEvents2.aspx".
>    Операция недопустима в текущем состоянии.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Я сегодня альтруист-стенографист, сделал правочку. Можете даже сами теперь поискать.

Comment: Посмотри вот здесь, [Visual Studio 2017 error: Unable to start program, An operation is not legal in the current state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692472/visual-studio-2017-error-unable-to-start-program-an-operation-is-not-legal-in)

Answer (score 1):

Переходим в **Отладка** -> **Параметры** -> **Общие** ->
 Снимите галочку с **"Включить отладку JavaScript для ASP.NET (Chrome и IE)**

Go to Tools > **Options** > **Debugging** > **General** and turn off the setting for **Enable JavaScript Debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE).**